# android-how to make a high quality 4 color gradient?

Tags: java, android, gradient

it is possible to make a `gradient` with 2 or 3 colors in Android. now is it possible to make a *high quality* gradient with 4 colors? I'm emphasizing on quality as there are some ways like putting 2 gradients beside each other but I think doesn't produce high quality result...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a 4 color gradient as a resource (in xml) but you can use the android.graphics.LinearGradient class to create one with more than 3 colors.  The constructor takes an array of colors and an array of positions.

Comment: but via using that class the above gradient can not be achieved, that's linear :(

Comment: @Soheil Were you able to figure it out? I'm trying to research the same thing.

Comment: If I were looking to do this today, I would look at using a vector drawable to manage the gradient.   Look up svg 4-way gradient and then hope that it will translate into a vector drawable. Otherwise you're looking at writing an openGL shader to make the gradient

Comment: in the constrained case of approximating the 4 quadrant gradient above, you can overlay 4 radial gradients where each transitions from color->transparent and the centers are at each corner.